# VLookup not returning all rows with a certain word

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am using Microsoft Excel.
I have 2 sheets. One labelled as New and one labelled as Old.
I have 125 rows with columns A-L on the sheet labelled as New
If Column B or F has the word Formal, I want it to go to the second sheet labelled Old.
I was testing this and could only get 1 item with the word to go over to the second page but since testing, I can't seem to find a way to make it work that's why i'm not including the Vlookup in this as none would be helpful.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` returns the first match, not all matches. You need a different formula such as `FILTER`.

Comment: @BigBen When I do the FILTER formula, I get #VALUE!
=FILTER(Sheet1!B2:C122=C3,"No results")

Comment: Please consider reading the [`FILTER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) docs, since your syntax is off.

Comment: @BigBen I went through that and I still can't get it to work. Can you write out what it would be?

Comment: @KingSchmoyer First, you haven't given us nearly enough information actually write the formula.  Second, there are THREE distinct arguments to FILTER and you have combined the first and second together.  you need something akin to `=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:L122,Sheet1!B2:B122=C3,"No Results")`  This says "get columns A-L from sheet1 for every row where that row's B column equals this sheet's C3."